# Approach to finding the minimum amount of numbers to add from a set to reach a certain number?

Tags: algorithm, numbers, set

Say I have a set containing positive integers, and a target number `m`. Is there an algorithm that finds the shortest way (using the least numbers) by adding them to each other to reach `m`? Each number in the set can be used more than once.

For example, if the set is `{1, 2}` and the target number is `7`, the shortest way is `2+2+2+1`, which has a length of 4 (instead of something like `2+2+1+1+1`, which has a length of 5)

I have already tried to code an algorithm to do this, but it is extremely slow. Here is the code I have:

```
import itertools


def can_make_sum(target, numbers_to_use):
    numbers = [False] * (target + 1)  # numbers[i] stores False if i cannot be made with numbers_to_use, or a tuple
    # storing its factors with the smallest multiplier
    for number in numbers_to_use:
        multiplier = 1
        while True:
            product = multiplier * number
            if product > target:
                break
            if not numbers[product]:  # If the value is False
                numbers[product] = (number, multiplier)
            else:
                if numbers[product][1] > multiplier:  # only replace the multiplier if it is smaller than the previous
                    numbers[product] = (number, multiplier)  # multiplier, so it is the shortest way to make that number

            multiplier += 1

    usable_numbers = []
    for product in numbers:
        if product != False:
            for _ in range(product[1]):
                usable_numbers.append(product[0])

    answer = []  # Final answer

    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        subsets = list(itertools.combinations(usable_numbers, i))  # All subsets of the usable numbers with length i
        for subset in subsets:
            total = sum(subset)
            if total == target:  # This is the smallest subset
                for num in subset:
                    for _ in range(numbers[num][1]):
                        answer.append(numbers[num][0])

                return answer


print(can_make_sum(13, {1, 2, 3}))
```

Just trying to make 13 with these three numbers already creates a noticeable delay before the answer comes out. Could this be improved and a lot faster, or is this already the fastest method?

Comment: In fact, I tried running `print(can_make_sum(135, {1, 2, 3, 7, 12}))`, and after a while my IDE crashed and gave `MemoryError`.

Comment: Can’t you just repeatedly pick the greatest number that won’t go over? - perhaps with some backtracking if you can’t hit the target exactly.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError If I have target `100` and numbers `[90, 9, 5]`, picking the greatest number would give us `99` and then become unable to find the next number to add, instead of finding `90 + 5 + 5`

Comment: @500-InternalServerError This cannot garantee that you get the smallest number of elements. For example, `[17 15 1]` to get `30`. Best solution is `15+15`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do an [A* search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm). The nodes of our graph are `(current_sum, smallest_number_used)`.  Each will connect with what you get if you add another number that is at most `smallest_number_used` in size.  Each edge has weight 1.  And the heuristic we use is that the distance to the end is at least `math.ceil(distance_left / smallest_number_used)`.

Here is code, along with several test cases.  I cheated a little, but the idea is the above.

```
import heapq
import math

def can_make_sum(target, numbers_to_use):
    numbers = list(reversed(sorted(numbers_to_use)))
    visited = set()
    to_explore = [(0, 0, 0, 0, None)]
    while 0 < len(to_explore):
        min_final_steps, current_steps, current_value, min_i, path = heapq.heappop(to_explore)
        key = (current_value, min_i)
        if key not in visited:
            visited.add(key)
            if current_value == target:
                answer = []
                while path is not None:
                    answer.append(path[0])
                    path = path[1]
                return answer

            next_value = current_value + numbers[min_i]
            if next_value <= target:
                next_steps = current_steps + 1
                heapq.heappush(
                    to_explore,
                    (
                       next_steps + math.ceil((target - next_value) / numbers[min_i]),
                       next_steps,
                       next_value,
                       min_i,
                       [numbers[min_i], path],
                    ))

            if min_i + 1 < len(numbers):
                heapq.heappush(
                    to_explore,
                    (
                       current_steps + math.ceil((target - current_value) / numbers[min_i + 1]),
                       current_steps,
                       current_value,
                       min_i + 1,
                       path,
                    ))

print(can_make_sum(13, [1, 2, 3]))
print(can_make_sum(7, [1, 2]))
print(can_make_sum(100, [90, 9, 5]))
print(can_make_sum(30, [17, 15, 1]))
print(can_make_sum(26, [17, 15, 4]))
print(len(can_make_sum(1234567, [25, 15, 4])))
```